# What's wrong with this BJT ESC?

Tags: transistors, circuit-design, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

I'm trying to drive a small BLDC motor, and I've come up with a design, built it, simulated it, but it doesn't seem to be working, either in the sim or on the protoboard. Usually I see P-type transistors in BLDC drives, but I'm short one, and I have a ton of NPNs.

The three inductors are the BLDC motor windings, each .7 mH and the winding resistance is 4.2 Ohms.
I've seen both types, and from what I understand, the PNP is just to reduce pin count.
[image: NPN BLDC diagram with flybacks]
[image: BLDC with PMOS and NMOS]

Are there any mistakes I'm making or principles I need to understand to make this work?
I'm driving the BJT with 5v (arduino power), 9V for motor. The motor itself jerks to position fine when I touch the 9V battery to some leads
Edit: I have a cheap oscilloscope, a bench supply and a multimeter. So far, the Arduino is functional.

### My design

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKQv9Z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Edit: Add photos of physical (bad soldering) **IGNORE LOOSE WIRE** (fell off while taking pic)
[image: Backside of the protoboard]
[image: Front side, 5V is connected to VIN]
[image: Salvaged HDD motor from Toshiba 2.5" HDD]

Edit: Arduino Code below:

```cpp
#define PIN_U_P 3
#define PIN_V_P 5
#define PIN_W_P 6

#define PIN_U_N 9
#define PIN_V_N 10
#define PIN_W_N 11


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(PIN_U_P, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(PIN_U_N, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(PIN_V_P, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(PIN_V_N, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(PIN_W_P, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(PIN_W_N, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
}

static int d = 20;
static int on = 1000;
void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(PIN_U_P, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(PIN_V_N, HIGH);
  delay(on);
  digitalWrite(PIN_U_P, LOW);
  digitalWrite(PIN_V_N, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
  delay(d);
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(PIN_V_P, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(PIN_W_N, HIGH);
  delay(on);
  digitalWrite(PIN_V_P, LOW);
  digitalWrite(PIN_W_N, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
  delay(d);
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(PIN_W_P, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(PIN_U_N, HIGH);
  delay(on);
  digitalWrite(PIN_W_P, LOW);
  digitalWrite(PIN_U_N, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
  delay(d);
}
```

Comment: The BJT is not controlled by the base. It's controlled by the base AND emitter, together. Your high-side BJT drive fail to account for that. You're applying voltages to the base relative to ground as if the BJT knows or cares what GND is. But how can it? It has zero pins connected to GND. It cannot even see GND.

Comment: then what do Q1, Q3 and Q5 do? I thought that, once I switched them on, then the positive-side has a reference voltage. (May be flawed, as it may need positive voltage to turn on first?)

Comment: @questionasker. Once you switch them off, that reference disappears. And you definitely don't want to switch them both on at once!

Comment: @Hearth <-What they said.

Comment: So, will a large resistance do to establish the reference?

Comment: @questionasker. No, I'm afraid you absolutely do need a voltage higher than Vcc. There's no way around that.

Comment: No, it will not. You either need to apply a base voltage that is referenced to the emitter voltage (so-called floating on the emitter) or apply a ground referenced base voltage high enough that the base-emitter voltage is always high enough, even as the emitter voltage rises relative to ground (reducing the B-E voltage) when load current flows.

Comment: I'm thinking 3.3V, even with my (tiny) experience with BJTs it seems as though this is a bit small. My motor doesn't complain though.

Comment: No reason why it shouldn't work, so there must be something you aren't telling us that is causing the problem. Please show us your actual circuit. What code are you using? What motor are you using? Do you have an oscilloscope?

Comment: The HDD motor has a fourth lead, although it doesn't have an obvious electrical connection. I have also forgotten resistors on the BJTs, are they probably still OK or dead? Arduino has 40mA drive strength...

Comment: @questionasker. if you forgot base resistors, the transistors are probably dead. The arduino might be too; that 40 mA isn't a maximum it can output period, that's a maximum it can output without damage.

Comment: _"The HDD motor has a fourth lead,"_ - Yes, the common connection. You can ignore it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To drive a motor with half-bridge topology (three of them in this case,) it is possible to use BJTsin a similar way it to how would be done with N-channel MOSFETs. Using BJTs will require a lot more current to drive the base than the current needed to drive the gate. That current would impose a much larger bootstrap solution.

Therefore, N-channel MOSFETs provide a better solution over BJTs.  To drive the N-channel, you'll need to create a bootstrap supply for the high side, one diode and one capacitor, and use a level shifter of opto-coupler to drive the gate. Looks like you'll need some changes to achieve success.

Answer (score 4):

Well, one thing that's wrong with it is that you're using BJTs.

But less facetiously, the bigger problem is that you're trying to use NPN transistors for high-side switching, without having a drive voltage higher than Vcc. So your high side drive is incapable of being saturated, and in fact you can't output a voltage any higher than 0.6~0.7 volts below your microcontroller's output voltage.

Comment: So, if I use 3V or 4V for the motor driver, will it suddenly not be broken?

Comment: @questionasker. It might heat up the transistors less, but I doubt your motor can run at such a low voltage. You need some way to pull the base of the high-side transistors above 9 volts, which is complicated, which is why you see motor drives with P-channel FETs and PNP BJTs. N-channel FETs are used in big industrial stuff because they have better characteristics, but that's always in conjunction with a power supply that can drive them above Vcc.

Comment: I'm using a salvaged HDD spindle motor, and it moves at 3.3V, although a bit weakly

Comment: In that case, it might work. But it should also work with a 9 volt supply as well if it does; I think you may have other problems. How much current does your motor need to spin? You may not be able to provide it enough with just a 2N3904. Are you sure your transistors are all functional, and remain functional? Because there's a lot of power being dissipated in the high-side transistors when you're driving them like this (can't give you the actual numbers without knowing the motor's stall current), and I wouldn't be surprised if it killed them.

Comment: Winding resistance is 4.2 Ohms, just less than 250 mA/V, so about 800 mA

Comment: @questionasker. That works out to a bit over a watt (approximately 250 mA * 4.7 V), which is more than enough to destroy a transistor in a tiny little TO-92 package. The rating I see on this [onsemi datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/1/2N3903_D-2310199.pdf) is 625 mW at an ambient temperature of 25 °C (the 1.5 watt figure that's also there is if you keep the plastic case at 25 °C, which is not really feasible), and I think even that's a bit generous.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133458/discussion-between-question-asker-and-hearth).

Comment: To drive the motor with NPN you'll need to create a bootstrap supply for the high side. The NPN base current will need to be around 10mA, to get enough emitter current. N-channel mosfet won't have that issue. This look like you'll need a complete redesign.

Comment: @Louis If that's it, then post it as an answer, possibly a suggested design also?